# Doctrine2 gedmo extension: what if record doesn't exist in specified locale?

Tags: doctrine-orm, translation

I've considered using gedmo for the website I'm working on right now to make some entites translatable. My question now is what if that specific user sets his locale to french and that not all translatable entities are translated to french? What will happen when I try to retrieve entities specifying a locale and it doesn't exist for some records ?

Comment: They fallback to the default language version.

Comment: thank you for that answer :) post it so I can accept it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was in the comment for a year and a half:
They fallback to the default language version.

– meze

Comment: It would be great if you added a source for ur answer just to make it more complete ;)